# How to get a post value on ASIFormDataRequest in DidFinishSelector method?

Tags: objective-c, ios, asihttprequest

Objective-C/iOS newbie here...

Given the following partial code...

```
...
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:myUrl];
    [request setDelegate:self];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(callComplete:)];
    [request setPostValue:@"Dilbert" forKey:@"name"];
...
```

...and...

```
- (void) callComplete:(ASIFormDataRequest*)request {
    // ? Determine what the value of the name parm was ?
}
```

...how can I, in the **callComplete** handler, get the value of the **name** post parameter?

I would have thought there would be something like [request **postValueForKey**:] method, but there is not. So unless someone knows a way to do this, I guess I'll just have to duplicate the data, either in the form of ivars or possibly with userInfo in the request.

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own method in the class to return what you want, but like you - I don't see a built in method to do that.

One note - ASIHttpRequest (as fast and easy as it is to use) is no longer being developed.  This framework is not and by all accounts never will be ARC compliant.  You may want to look at using another framework (CF-Networking or something similar) instead.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried to do it, but this might work:

```
- (void) callComplete:(ASIFormDataRequest*)request {

    NSString *name;
    for (NSDictionary *parameter in [request postData]) {
        if ([[parameter objectForKey:@"key"] isEqualToString:@"name"]) {
            name = [parameter objectForKey:@"value"];
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such method postData in ASIFormDataRequest.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
- (void) callComplete:(ASIFormDataRequest*)request {  

     NSMutableData *postBody=[request postBody]; 

     NSString *stringPostBody = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:postBody   

     encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```